# Have I correctly specified my GAMM model?

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, validation

I am new to GAMM models and I would like to ask you whether I designed the model correctly.

I aim to evaluate the relationship of a blood protein (independent variable) with the disease scoring system (dependent variable). I examined the effect of the protein level on the score recorded at baseline, the second and fifth years. Since all individuals were measured at these time points, I could include the random factors in my model. Moreover, I had to add confounding variables (form, BMI, age, and gender). 
In the beginning, I checked the normality of data and analysed several models (lmer and glmer) with various distributions (e.g., normal, negative binomial, gamma), but their residual distributions looked weird (in Q-Q plots). So, I discussed this topic on CrossValidated and a user advised me to use GAM. I read some articles and found manuals, but I am not sure about my model design.

My data:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1invel66Ns-Yh5oOIrJ9kGTC0Og9OwjFf/view?usp=sharing

The *score* variable is the sum of various subscores of joints, which were computed by two independent evaluators. They evaluated all joints on the ordinal scale or count the number of affected joints. As a result, *score* values are positive integers, which looks to me as NB distribution.
Since the disease could progress into severe *form*, I also specify “ero” and ”nero” forms.
*Time* is three examination points and treated as the factor.
*ID* represents individual subjects.
Confounding variables (*evaluator*, *time*, *age*, *gender*, *form*) are required based on literature, and the protein level (*prot*) could be affected by *time*.
I included the *ID* as a random intercept and also adjusted my model for the random slope of *time* within *ID*. (I hope I described it correctly.)

I have designed this model:

```
mod <- mgcv::gam(score ~ evaluator + time + s(age) + gender + form + s(prot, by= time, k=30) +
             s(id , bs = 're') +  s(id,time, bs = 're'),
           data = data, method = 'REML', family = nb())
```

After modelling and checking using `gam.check()` and `check.gamViz()`, the output did not look optimal and I am unsure about the quality of my design.

```
Method: REML   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 12 iterations.
Gradient range [-0.0006587177,1.182036e-05]
(score 1234.357 & scale 1).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [1.367248e-05,44.5528].
Model rank =  626 / 626 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

                                       k'      edf k-index p-value    
s(age)                           9.00e+00 3.54e+00    0.78  <2e-16 ***
s(biochem_val):examination_rtg0  2.90e+01 2.46e+00    0.73  <2e-16 ***
s(biochem_val):examination_rtg24 2.90e+01 1.00e+00    0.73  <2e-16 ***
s(biochem_val):examination_rtg60 2.90e+01 1.00e+00    0.73  <2e-16 ***
s(id_rtg)                        1.31e+02 1.26e+02      NA      NA    
s(id_rtg,examination_rtg)        3.93e+02 3.33e-03      NA      NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

[image: Checking plots]

I thank everybody for any contribution and comments in advance.